# parse html and remove text preserving TAGS

Tags: php, dom, html-parsing

The PHP simple dom allows us to take an HTML page and extract only the markup, leaving the text.  Like this:

```
echo file_get_html('http://www.google.com/')->plaintext;
```

I am looking for the **opposite** of that method.  Remove all of the text and preserve only the tags.  Does that exist?  I can't seem to find any reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the actual W3C DOM api (not SimpleHtmlDom) anything is a node, not only the element nodes. With XPath you can select them using the `text()` function.

```
$html = <<<'HTML'
<html><body>
<div>
  TEXT<div>TEXT</div>
</div>
</body></html>
HTML;

$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//text()') as $node) {
  $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
}

echo $document->saveHtml($document->documentElement);
```

Output:

```
<html><body><div><div></div></div></body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont use any search and replace php function or regexp. They're meant to parse and minupulate strings and larger texts. Use something in line of HTML DOM parsing.

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm

For example, to find all the img tags in an html document you'd do the following:

```
// Create DOM from URL or file
 $html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');

// Find all images 
foreach($html->find('img') as $element) 
       echo $element->src . '<br>';

// Find all links 
foreach($html->find('a') as $element) 
       echo $element->href . '<br>';
```

if you go to the URL below you'll learn how to find html elements within a loaded html page

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#section_find

this is the most efficient way of going about it. this has a built in finder to locate html elements and to form it to your needs.